# Why doesn't 'tf.scatter_nd_update' support string?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my model, I need to maintain an extremely long 2-D variable tensor，which has several columns and many rows, and its dtype is string. In every training step, I need to update several individal rows of that tensor. 'tf.scatter_nd_update' meets my requirements perfectly，except that it doesn't support string. Is there any work-around ways to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1261, in _run_fn
    self._extend_graph()
  File "tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1295, in _extend_graph
    tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ScatterNdUpdate' with these attrs. Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]

         [[Node: ScatterNdUpdate = ScatterNdUpdate[T=DT_STRING, Tindices=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@Variable"], use_locking=true](Variable, HashCollectiveAndUpdate, HashCollectiveAndUpdate:1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is surprising that [`tf.scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) does not with with strings, especially since [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) does work. You can reproduce the same behaviour with a function like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_scatter_nd_update(ref, indices, updates, use_locking=True):
    indices = tf.convert_to_tensor(indices)
    updates = tf.convert_to_tensor(updates)
    # Make a mask for elements to replace
    m = tf.ones_like(updates, dtype=tf.bool)
    s = tf.shape(ref)
    mask = tf.scatter_nd(indices, m, s)
    # Make tensor of replacement values put in place
    upd_scatter = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, s)
    # Select replacement values for replaced positions
    new_value = tf.where(mask, upd_scatter, ref)
    # Do assignment
    return tf.assign(ref, new_value, use_locking=use_locking)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    var = tf.Variable([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']])
    var_upd = my_scatter_nd_update(var, [[0, 1], [1, 2]], ['g', 'h'])
    sess.run(var.initializer)
    print(sess.run(var_upd))
    # [[b'a' b'g' b'c']
    #  [b'd' b'e' b'h']]
```

It is some more work than a proper update operation, but the result should be equivalent.

Comment: I‘m afraid this can't meet my requirement.Because the 'ref' variable is extremely long, and distributed in several parameter servers. I must avoid to calculate any tensor has the same shape as 'ref', otherwise will cause serious performance issues.

Comment: @SeekerYb Well, I'm not sure there is any other alternative. As you said, there is just no registered kernel for it. The source of the issue seems to be in [this point of the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/scatter_nd_op.cc#L380-L386). Maybe if you added `TF_CALL_string(REGISTER_SCATTER_ND_UPDATE_CPU);` there it would just work? If you are willing to try your own build you could try that. Otherwise, I'd consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) about it.

Comment: thank you all the same.I may open an issue by myself.